# Can squid work as reverse proxy server for ftp, pop3 and smtp

Tags: configuration, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

OS is Ubuntu 14.04
Can squid work as reverse proxy server for ftp, pop3 and smtp?
I need a server can work as reverse proxy server mode  to proxy the http and ftp.

I configure quid3 but I find it can only work forward mode for ftp and pop3 and smtp, can you give me an example of how to configure the squid as reverse proxy mode for (passive)ftp and smtp?

if it can not do it, can anyother know the software can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squid is a HTTP proxy (usually operated as a Forward Proxy). It does support FTP also. It does not support POP3 and SMTP.

You should look at something like HAProxy if you want a Reverse Proxy for protocols other than HTTP.